# converting while in shell script to windows command file

Tags: bash, shell, cmd

I have a shell script with sample code as follows..am trying to convert into a `.cmd` file.. can anyone provide inputs on what is the syntax for while and case in `.cmd` file?

```
while getopts "c" flag
do
   # In case clear option
   case $flag in
   c) code
      exit
   ;;
   esac
done
```

Comment: Why convert. Just install cygwin on windows, and run your script.

Comment: cannot install cygwin on server unfortunately..need to convert to windows..

Comment: @Ashwini - do you have any inputs?

Answer (score 0):

You should refer to Microsoft's [documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/batch.mspx?mfr=true).

Comment: i dont find any whle loop syntax

Comment: Looks like you should use `if` and `goto`.